# "Ошибка определения принадлежности процессов" при подключении к серверу 1С 8.3 в Docker

Tags: 1с, docker

Столкнулся с проблемой подключения к серверу 1С, который запущен в контейнере docker, основанном на linux ubuntu 14.04. Сам сервер устанавливается, работает, это можно проверить командой `ps -eax | grep v8`, но при попытке открыть его через консоль кластера (на windows 10), выдается ошибка: "ошибка определения принадлежности клиентского и серверного процессов одному компьютеру". В интернете все пишут, что нужно адрес сервера прописать в файле hosts на клиенте и тогда ошибка уйдет, но в данном случае это не помогает. Я пробовал прописать в hosts все возможные комбинации ip+name, это не сработало. Прошу помощи, очень хочется изучить эту технологию.

Версия 1С - 8.3.10.2505, Windows 10, Docker 17.06.0-ce-win19(12801), Ubuntu 14.04.

Свою сборку базирую на dockerfile от temrdm: https://github.com/temrdm/1c_server

Comment: какую технологию вы хотите изучить?

Comment: технологию docker

Comment: тогда лучше обратите внимание на официальные руководства, там подробно рассказано как использовать докер.

Comment: спасибо, капитан очевидность. еще что-нибудь скажете?

Answer (score 0):

Задача состоит в том, чтобы добиться правильного адреса при пинге через имя.
Допустим, в hosts прописан следующий адрес
192.168.56.201     SERVER_1C
Тогда на клиенте ping SERVER_1C должен выдавать этот ip. Возможна проблема из-за использования ipv6. Дополнительно стоит проверить как выполняется этот пинг на самом сервере.

Answer (score 0):

При запуске командой docker, либо в docker-compose необходимо задать следующие параметры для сервиса (контейнера):

```
hostname: your-srv
domainname: your.domain
```

Далее необходимо, чтобы `your-srv.your.domain` резолвился на компьютере откуда выполняется подключение, для этого достаточно добавить запись в `hosts`, либо на сервере DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Если указать что контейнер использует сеть
хоста то будет работать и без правки hosts.
В docker-compose.yml:

network_mode: "host"

Или при вызове docker run:

--network host